# Migration em mais de um banco

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Preciso rodar o comando `php artisan migrate` e cada **migration** vá para seu respectivo banco de dados, tenho os seguinte código no `.env`:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=163.25.138.18
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=book_posts
DB_USERNAME=teste
DB_PASSWORD=teste1

DB_BOOKLOGIN_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_BOOKLOGIN_HOST=163.25.138.18
DB_BOOKLOGIN_PORT=3306
DB_BOOKLOGIN_DATABASE=book_usuarios
DB_BOOKLOGIN_USERNAME=teste
DB_BOOKLOGIN_PASSWORD=teste1

DB_BOOKMATERIAIS_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_BOOKMATERIAIS_HOST=163.25.138.18
DB_BOOKMATERIAIS_PORT=3306
DB_BOOKMATERIAIS_DATABASE=book_materiais
DB_BOOKMATERIAIS_USERNAME=teste
DB_BOOKMATERIAIS_PASSWORD=teste1
```

Usei a variável `$connection` nas *migrations* assim:

```
protected $connection = 'bookmateriais';

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('locais', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('nome');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('locals');
}
```

Porém quando rodo `php artisan migrate` vai para o banco default, alguém sabe como direcionar as **migration** para seus respectivos bancos de dados?

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver!

Para quem precisar segue a solução:

```
Schema::connection('bookmateriais')->create('locais', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->bigIncrements('id');
   $table->string('nome');
   $table->timestamps();
   $table->softDeletes();
});
```

Basta usar connection após `Schema::`